# How can I extract the short form of an igraph object as a string?

Tags: r, graph, igraph

`igraph` returns a short hand form of an igraph object in R:

```
> myGraph
IGRAPH DNW- 15 28 -- 
+ attr: name (v/c), weight (e/n)
+ edges (vertex names):
```

I would like to extract the `IGRAPH DNW- 15 28 --` part as a string, however all possibilities coming to mind such as `print(myGraph)`, `summary(myGraph)`, `as.character(myGraph)`, `names(myGraph)` etc. don't work.

How do I extract that string?

Comment: `capture.output(print(myGraph))[1]`?

Comment: @lukeA That is new to me, but seems to work. Thank you! If you post this as an answer, I'll gladly accept it.

Comment: @lukeA @Eekhoorn Use `summary`, not `print`, `print` might print the whole graph, depending on options.